# If i use glTranslatex instead of glTranslatef, i don't see anything !

Tags: android, opengl-es

i am writting a little program in OpenGL ES for Android (api 3) that show a white triangle upon a black screen. But what was my astonishment when i noticed that changing a call to glTranslatef to glTranslatex (in onDrawFrame() method) made my triangle invisible ! Could anybody explain me what is happening.

Here my code for the Renderer

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.GLU;

public class TheRenderer implements Renderer {

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -6); // Here my problem
    triangle.draw(gl);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if (height == 0)
        height = 1;
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 60.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 1, 10);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

}

private GLSimple2DTriangle triangle = new GLSimple2DTriangle();
}
```

Here the code for Triangle

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class GLSimple2DTriangle {

    public GLSimple2DTriangle(){
        buildVerticesBuffer();
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl){
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GL10.GL_SHORT, 0, verticesBuffer);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, VERTICES_NUMBER);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }

    private void buildVerticesBuffer(){
        final short vertices [] = {
                +0, +1,
                +1, -1,
                -1, -1
        };

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * SHORTS_SIZE_BYTES);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        verticesBuffer = byteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
        verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
        verticesBuffer.rewind();
    }

    private ShortBuffer verticesBuffer;
    private static final byte SHORTS_SIZE_BYTES = 2;
    private static final byte COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;
    private static final byte VERTICES_NUMBER = 3;
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glTranslatex` is the fixed-point version. OpenGL-ES uses a 16.16 fixed point format, so integer coordinates should be shifted 16 bits to the left to get you the same result. Your translate call would then become `glTranslatex(0, 0, -6 << 16)`. Right now, without the shift, the value -6 is actually -0.00009 (-6 / 65536), so your object is being clipped by the near plane.

Comment: Thank you very much :) And do you think i should use float version or fixed-point version if i want to optimize ?